# How to replace with starting and ending with asterik

Tags: java, string, replace, case-insensitive

How do I get the required output?

input string :

```
 " software Company(1920 of 2012)(sb.2)(sb.3) IBM on established (2009)"
```

word to be searched -

```
"software company(1920 of 2012)"
```

Output

```
*software Company(1920 of 2012)*(sb.2)(sb.3) IBM on established (2009)
```

In short I have to find a phrase and replace the same phrase with starting and ending with asterisk (*), IGNORING THE CASE, and MATCH EXACT WORLD i

Comment: Stop SHOUTING at us.  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Are you trying to see if a given string contains the second string?

Comment: You could have easily googled it. Think a bit before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
String original =  " software Company(1920 of 2012)(sb.2)(sb.3) IBM on established (2009)";
String subString = "software company(1920 of 2012)";
System.out.println("New String is: " + original.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(subString), "*$0*"));
```

The `(?i)` is added to make it case insensitive, and the [`Pattern#quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) is used to escape special regex characters in your substring.

This prints:

```
New String is:  *software Company(1920 of 2012)*(sb.2)(sb.3) IBM on established (2009)
```